# Not getting custom key when retrieving data from Treksoft

Tags: php, infusionsoft

I have made some custom keys using your web view. Now I’m saving the data in which I have placed the custom keys with an underscore at the start but the problem is when I try to retrieve the data I don’t get the custom key. Can somebody tell me what is going wrong?

I’m using rest API

This is how I'm trying to retrieve the data

```
infusionsoftService->contacts()->get()
```

the contact function is the infusionsoft sdk function but here is it's implementation

```
/**
 * @return \Infusionsoft\Api\ContactService
 */
public function contacts($api = 'rest')
{
    if ($api == 'xml') {
        return $this->getApi('ContactService');
    }

    return $this->getRestApi('ContactService');
}
```

Comment: Can we see you code?

Comment: @yuga sure. I'll edit the post

Comment: @yuga do you any reason.